# how sum of all rows by group in same row in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have little problem, but i can't figure out, i have tables called points,
this is my table structures

```
id| fight_id| side | user_id  | amount | events 
        | 16    |  2      |   20    | 5000     | 4
        | 16    |  2      |    2      |  1000     | 4
        | 16    |  1      |   20    | 4000     | 4
```

i wan to sum by group side in same row but my problem is im getting wrong value , in side i get 6000, and in side 8000

this is my wrote code

```
 $events = 4;

    $points = "SELECT *, SUM(a.amount) AS meron, SUM(b.amount) AS wala FROM points a LEFT OUTER JOIN points b ON a.events = b.events AND a.fight_id = b.fight_id  WHERE a.fight_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM fights WHERE events = '$events') AND a.events = '$events' GROUP BY a.side, b.side";
    $points_query = $conn->query($points);
    while($row = $points_query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $points_list = "SELECT * FROM points WHERE events = '".$row['events']."' AND fight_id = '".$row['fight_id']."' AND side = '".$row['side']."'";
        $points_query_list = $conn->query($points_list);
          while($list_row = $points_query_list->fetch_assoc()) {
            if($row['meron'] < $row['wala']) {
                $lbets = ((($row['wala'] * 0.915) / $row['meron']) + 1);
                // $lbets = $list_row['amount'] * roundDown($lbets,2);
                echo $row['meron'] . "-" . $row['wala'] . "-" .$lbets . "-" . $list_row['user_id'] . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
```

the row['meron'] is side 1 and row['wala'] is side 2 but what i get in meron is 6000 and in wala is 8000 its totally wrong , the value must be 4000 in meron and 6000 in wala,  whats wrong in my code, i tried to use LEFT OUTER JOIN

thank you

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about all the non-sql stuff for now, and instead focus on the query

Comment: yep, but can you help me with this?

Comment: If that's a route you want to explore, then see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)